# Django serialization validation optimization for bulk create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write an api to process large number of rows of data using `bulk_create` on zipped csv records. but when `serializer.is_valid()` is called to validate the data before calling `serializer.save()`, it takes a long time to validate due to the foreign key constraint for `device_id(sensorReading_device)`.

I've tried `prefetch_related()` & `select_related()` and nested serializer and the performance is similar or worse as i suspect the modelserializer is committing the n+1 DB roundtripping problem for validation due to the foreign key. The only method which worked is to remove the foreign key in my model and implement as charfield and it became blazingly fast but it means there will be no more foreign key constraint. Is the removal of foreign key the way forward or am I missing something?

heres my code and any advice is greatly appreciated!

serializer.py

```
class SensorReadingListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        sensor_readings = [SensorReading(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return SensorReading.objects.bulk_create(sensor_readings)

class SensorReadingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    device_qs = Device.objects.all()
    sensorReading_device = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(label='SensorReading device', many=True, queryset=device_qs)

    class Meta:
        model = ReadingsModel.SensorReading
        fields = ('id', 'device_timestamp', 'server_timestamp', 'payload', 'sensorReading_device')
        list_serializer_class = SensorReadingListSerializer
```

model.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120)
    device_deviceType = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_softwareVersion = models.ForeignKey(SoftwareVersion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SensorReading(models.Model):
    device_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
    server_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
    payload = JSONField()
    sensorReading_device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # sensorReading_device = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

view.py

```
class SensorReadingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows SensorReading to be viewed or edited.
    """

    serializer_class = SensorReadingSerializer
    # queryset = SensorReading.objects.all().select_related('device')
    # queryset = SensorReading.objects.prefetch_related('sensorReading_device').all()
    queryset = SensorReading.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)


    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def post_readings_zip(self, request):
        if not sys.warnoptions:
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

        # print(self.queryset.len())
        request_file = request.FILES['zipped_file']
        device_id = request.data['device_id']
        # server_timestamp = datetime.datetime.today

        if Device.objects.filter(device_id=device_id).exists():
            print('device exist')
            if zipfile.is_zipfile(request_file):
                print('file is zip')
                zf = zipfile.ZipFile(request_file)
                filelist = zf.namelist()
                data = []
                print("Processing data: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                for csv_file_name in filelist:
                    with zf.open(csv_file_name) as reading_csv:
                        rc = reading_csv.read()
                        c = csv.StringIO(rc.decode())
                        for row in c:
                            row = row.rstrip()
                            data.append({'payload': {'data': row}, 'sensorReading_device': device_id})
                print("Done processing csvs: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                # data = [{'payload': {'data': 'hello world payload 01'}, 'sensorReading_device': '001'},
                #         {'payload': {'data': 'hello world payload 02'}, 'sensorReading_device': '001'}]
                # qs = SensorReadingSerializer.setup_eager_loading(self.queryset)
                serializer = SensorReadingSerializer(data=data, many=True)
                # print(repr(serializer))
                print("Validating serializer: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    print("Saving: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                    serializer.save()
                    print("Done: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
                    # return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201, safe=False)
                    return JsonResponse({'status':serializer.data}, status=201, safe=False)
                return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400, safe=False)
            else:
                return JsonResponse(
                    {'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, 'message': 'Bad Request: Uploaded file is not a zip'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,'message': 'Device ID does not exist, please register'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add index_db? Have a quick read at [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/#use-standard-db-optimization-techniques). Have you analysed your querys with django-toolbar or anything similar?